# CodeIgniter does not add watermark with image_lib

Tags: php, codeigniter, watermark

I'm trying to add watermark on uploaded image, but it doesn't works.. There is my code, I can't see any errors there..

```
$data['photo_name'] = $data['slogan'];
            $data['photo_ext'] = end(explode('.', $photoValue));

            $data['photo_name'] = $data['photo_name'] . '.' . $data['photo_ext'];

                file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/'. PHOTOS_UPLOAD_FOLDER . $data['photo_name'], file_get_contents($photoValue));
//                $this->resize_image($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/'. PHOTOS_UPLOAD_FOLDER . $data['photo_name']);
                $this->simpleimage->load($data['photosData']['uploadFolder'] . $data['photo_name']);
                $this->simpleimage->cutFromCenter(450, 450);
                $this->simpleimage->save($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/'. PHOTOS_UPLOAD_FOLDER . $data['photo_name']);

                // add watermark
                $configImg = array();
                $configImg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $configImg['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
                $configImg['source_image'] = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/'. PHOTOS_UPLOAD_FOLDER . $data['photo_name'];
                $configImg['wm_overlay_path'] = base_url('assets/logo.png');
                $configImg['wm_opacity'] = '50';
                $configImg['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
                $configImg['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';

                $this->image_lib->initialize($configImg);
                $this->image_lib->watermark();
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                print_r($configImg);
```

and it does not printing any errors.
it prints only my array

```
Array
(
    [image_library] => gd2
    [wm_type] => overlay
    [source_image] => ../king-include/uploads/possibly-the-best-youtube-comment-ever-.jpg
    [wm_overlay_path] => http://www.domain.info/parser/assets/logo.png
    [wm_opacity] => 100
    [wm_vrt_alignment] => top
    [wm_hor_alignment] => center
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to put display_errors() before clear() function? The second sample of code is different as $configImg is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

source_image : Sets the source image name/path. The path must be a relative or absolute server path, not a URL.

The problem is with your watermarking overlay image. Set it with correct path and try again.